# Baffling FileNotFoundError on Windows

Tags: python, windows

The problem that I'm having is frankly baffling. I was doing some python coding, come back the next day, and without changing anything, the code stopped working, giving a `FileNotFoundError`. I've whittled it down to a laughably simple minimum code to produce the error.

```
f = open('positions.tsv','w')
```

Which produces the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/mrhel/Documents/GitHub/gas-collisions/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    f = open('positions.tsv','w')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'positions.tsv'
```

I have been scouring the internet for hours for a solution but everything I come across is someone trying to create a file in a folder that doesn't exist or forgetting to set the mode to `'w'`. I copied the exact code that this is happening with onto a Linux machine and it runs just fine, it is specifically not working on my Windows 10 machine.

I have tried rebooting the computer, which doesn't work either. Why would this simple line of code not work specifically on Windows?

Edit:
How I run the code is either `python test.py` or `C:/Users/mrhel/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.8.exe c:/Users/mrhel/Documents/GitHub/gas-collisions/test.py`

In any case, the expected behavior according to the `open()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) 
is that `positions.tsv` should be created upon calling this function with the `'w'` mode.

When I do create the file in advance, I get an error when I try to write to it.

```
f = open('positions.tsv','w')
f.write('testing')
f.close()
```

Error:

```
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/mrhel/Documents/GitHub/gas-collisions/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    f.close()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Edit 2:
I tried creating a file and reading it, and that works as expected. It's specifically writing that isn't working

Edit 3:
So since it runs in another folder, I decided to check for write permissions, and this is what I got. When I check properties of the folder with windows, all users have allow ticked.

```
>>> os.access('my_folder', os.W_OK)
False
```

This is clearly a permissions issue, but I'm not sure how to rectify it.

Comment: Where is `potisions.tsv` saved? And how do you run your python code?

Comment: I do not, but the documentation states that when using `'w'` mode, the file is created if it does not exist. I am using python 3.8, so the documentation should be describing the correct behavior for this version.

Comment: `open('positions.tsv','w')` will try to create (or overwrite) that file in the Current Working Directory. You might get a clue by printing out what that is right before the `open` via a `print(os.getcwd())` (after an `import os` of course).

Comment: @martineau I've tried that, and it gives correctly the directory that the code file is in

Comment: Could you try running your python prompt as an admin?

Comment: Or moving your script to some other folder?

Comment: I tried with admin, and it didn't work, but I tried copying the contents to a new file on the desktop, and it works now. So it seems that there's some issue with write permissions. This code is in a folder created by github desktop, so maybe when it creates the repo, it might be messing with permissions. Any idea how I might fix that?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue by creating a new folder via github desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a result of "Controlled Folder Access" in Windows Defender Ransomware Protection. Turning off this feature allows it to function as expected. It's not clear how Ransomware Protection decided that my code is not to be trusted, but for posterity's sake, that is how this was fixed.